# AWS SWF createTimer promise not returning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I want a loop that after each iteration waits for a while. I'm trying to use a timer to do the waiting, but the timer never returns, so the below code only runs once and then waits forever. When I remove the timer condition, the code executes successfully. There are no errors, it just waits...

Any help is appreciated!

```
@override
public void doWorkflow() {
    validate("test", 1);
}

@Asynchronous
private void validate(String id, int retries, Promise<?>... waitFor) {
    Promise<Boolean> isValid = activityClient.validate(id);

    doWork(id, retries, isValid);
}

@Asynchronous
private void doWork(String id, int retries, Promise<Boolean> isValid) {
    if (!isValid.get()) {
        return;
    }

    Promise<Void> waitFor = decisionContext.getWorkflowClock().createTimer(5);

    validate(id, retries - 1, waitFor);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using Spring to set up the application. To get the decision context I was using

```
@Autowired
DecisionContext decisionContext
```

The problem is when constructing the Workflow implementation I didn't use a scope. The solution was to add the scope="workflow" attribute:

```
<bean id="myWorkflow" class="com.example.myWorkflowImpl" scope="workflow">
```

After doing this, the workflow history began showing the TimerStarted event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problems with your code. First I would look at the workflow history (either through console or by printing it using [WorkflowExecutionHistoryPrinter](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/common/WorkflowExecutionHistoryPrinter.java)) to see if timer is scheduled and if it ever fires. If the history looks OK I would get "asynchronous thread dump" using [WorkflowExecutionFlowThreadDumper](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/common/WorkflowExecutionFlowThreadDumper.java) to see what exactly your code waits for.

Comment: Following your advice, I can see the timer wasn't firing